# BinarySearch vs For loop

Tags: java, arrays, search, iteration

Quite simply, performance wise, how does using `Arrays.binarySearch()` compare to using an iterative loop (through all items in the array - a linear search) to find a value in an Array or ArrayList? Would the end user ever be able to see any delays using either?

Also are there any specific situations where one method is better than the other?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: NB binary search can and should be implemented iteratively/using a loop. I assume you mean linear search where every item of the list is checked until a match if found.

Comment: @delnan Yes, you assumed correctly. I'll edit my question

Comment: Brush up on some Big-O notation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o/487278#487278

Comment: @Downvoters I don't mind downvotes but please explain why. This question already has multiple answers and seems useful

Comment: @Andy, I didn't down vote, but this is information that is easily looked up, and plentifully explained/discussed.  I'm guessing the down votes are for lack of research effort.

Answer (score 5):

Binary search happens in O(log(n)) time.  Linear search (that is, iterating the entire array) occurs in O(n) time.  There's **huge** benefits in using binary search when and where you can.

In general, the situations in which you should use a binary search is when you're guaranteed that the data you have is sorted, and is above some minimum amount (since you won't notice much performance boost if you're searching 5 items with linear or binary search).

However, note that `Arrays#binarySearch` only works on arrays, and not `ArrayList` - those are fundamentally different objects.  If you wanted a binary search on a `List` collection, then make use of [`Collections#binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29).

Comment: Provided the array is sorted, and for a certain minimum size.

Comment: That's the bar requirement for the binary search algorithm, anyway.  But yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is helpful. You mention that the data must be sorted, so what effect does using `Arrays.sort()` have on this comparence of performance. Also, the array would probably only ever be around 200 records so I don't suppose performance would be that noticable.

Comment: Well, log(200)/log(2) < 200, so you *would* notice some performance increase when searching (you'd have to ask a maximum of eight times as opposed to 200).  Sorting the array would mean you take an O(n*log(n)) hit, since that's the performance of the Arrays#sort.  By rule of Big-Oh notation, your overall runtime would be O(n*log(n)) because of the added, heavier cost of sorting the data.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just to clarify then, if the array is unsorted then it's going to be quicker just to loop through each element of the array but if it is sorted then binary search is definately quicker. Sorry, I've never really met the Big-Oh notation before but I'm pretty sure I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search requires that the array/list be sorted.  This must be considered before performing such a search.

The benefit of a binary search is that the worst case run time is O(log(n)). On the other hand, the worst case for an iterative search is O(n), regardless of whether or not it has been sorted.  Depending on the size of the array/list, and the data and its qualifications for order, the user may or may not notice a performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

That will completely depend on the data in question.  First, your array needs to be sorted.  If your array is very small, you may not see a significant difference.

If your array is very large and sorted, you will see a significant speed increase when using a binary search.

**Note:** As your data set grows larger, binary search is increasingly faster.  This is because of the nature of the growth of linear vs. logarithmic algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is sorted then you have to use binary search it will be very helpful and fast in execution with time complexity of O(logn) and in case array you have to call Arrays.binarySearch() and in case of any collection it might be the list or set you have to call Collections binarySearch method

Answer (score 0):

Binary search works for Collections (`ArrayList` is implementation of it) too. Method is in `java.util.Collections`

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)`
```

Your element class should implement `Comparable` interface and implement `public int compareTo(T o);`
 method